# Can't find DocumentsListQuery.DocumentID or DocumentsListQuery.folderBaseUri

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, google-docs-api

Every code sample out there that I've found to list folders uses
`DocumentsListQuery.DocumentID` or `DocumentsListQuery.folderBaseUri`, neither of which I can access. Those members do not exist. Am I using a wrong version or anything?

I'm using VS 2010.

Comment: I fugured they might not be available from to VB since they are unmanaged - and all the samples I found where actually in c#.
But no luck, I still can't access them from c#.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the latest version of the client library (http://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/downloads/list) and check out the .NET samples in the docs (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/). They are in C#, but it should be easy to adapt them to VB.NET.